# Typed version of Newton's Principia Mathematica

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request

I need a typed pdf version of Newton's Principia. Is it available for free online? And I also need the proof of universal law of gravity and the elliptical orbits of planets(If there's no typed version).

Comment: Related question Phys.SE: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8265/2451

Answer (score 3):

[Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/) has it [at this link](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/28233/28233-pdf.pdf) (PDF file). But it's in Latin, from præfatio to finis.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an 1846 version at [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/newtonspmathema00newtrich), translated into English by Andrew Motte.

The direct pdf scan is linked [here](https://ia600300.us.archive.org/8/items/newtonspmathema00newtrich/newtonspmathema00newtrich.pdf).

Here is another Andrew Motte version, [all typed](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Mathematical_Principles_of_Natural_Philosophy_%281846%29). The entire contents appear to be here, but it is broken into a pdf per chapter (like 40 or so pdfs). You could download each of them and merge into one book if desired.

Comment: It's also got it pdf-scanned and plaintext-typed (though I can't see a typed pdf version)

Comment: I added the direct link to the pdf in the post. Note on the side the link to the pdf at about 50.1 mb.

Comment: I know that; what I mean is that it's scanned & not typed but they've also got a typed version on the side, though not as a pdf

Comment: ignore that (my computer messed up and wouldn't read it properly)

Comment: Oh snap, this thing is ocr'ed and searchable. Nevermind what I said.

Comment: I realised the same thing but felt that the OP had probably got what he wanted anyway lol

Comment: They have an OCR-ed version as a Kindle book, and it would be simple to convert that to a pdf (Calibre software) - BUT it seems to be full of glitches, such as missing characters and spaces inserted into words, unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, found something cool, but it is busted into pieces.